# Cocoapod Library: Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am using `ProximiioMapbox` cocoapod library, and it says i can not import it on XCode 12.
It compiles well after `pod install`, but when i add `import ProximiioMapbox` in a swift file, it shows error like the title of this question.

Here are the ways i tried.

1. Clean Build Folder
2. Remove `Derived data` and restart XCode.
3. In Podfile, I tried to set the config.build_settings[`SWIFT_VERSION`] = `5.2.4`// also tried 5.0, 5.1, 4.2
4. removed `Podfile.lock`, and `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`. also tried `pod update`.

None of those worked, Anyone knows how i can solve this? As far as i am concerned, `ProximiioMapbox` sdk was compiled with Swift 5.2.

> `Dont' close this question. No answers on stackoverflow for cocoapod framework`.